# eager loading collection relationship in EF code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Im using entity framework code first 4.3 in c#

I got the following classes:

```
Class A
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

Class B
{
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There is one to many realationship from A to B.
When i try to load B list from A. I only get the first element from the list.

When i execute the following code, i expect a2 to contain both b's, but actually it contains only one. does anyone can help spot the problem?

```
B b = new B() {Name = "b"};
A a = new A() {Name = "a", 
Bs = new List<B>() { new B() {Name = "b1"}, new B() {Name = "b2"} };

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
context.As.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
}
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
var a2 = (from a in context.As.Include(a => a.Bs)
        where a.Name == "a"
        select a).Single();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your actual code - the code you posted doesn't compile, but with some small changes to some of your brackets and variable naming  it does - but I get a different result than you, a2 contains both B's, as expected, so the problem may lie somewhere else.  Here's the entire console app:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Model : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B() { Name = "b" };
        var a1 = new A()
            {
                Name = "a",
                Bs = new List<B>() { new B() { Name = "b1" }, new B() { Name = "b2" } }
            };

        using (var context = new Model())
        {
            context.As.Add(a1);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        using (var context = new Model())
        {
            var a2 = (from a in context.As.Include(a => a.Bs)
                      where a.Name == "a"
                      select a).Single();

            Console.WriteLine(a2.Bs.Count);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Using your code (that worked just fine), i managed to understand that the problem was the my classes implemented Icomparable badly (the comparator was buggy). Thanks.